# What are the components of a Von Neumann probe?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, exploration

A Von Neumann probe is a theoretical space probe based on the 'Universal Assembler' concept. The probe would be capable of using raw materials found in the universe to create copies of itself, thereby spreading throughout the universe with the goal of exploring it.

At the most basic level, I would assume that it would consist of a universal assembler coupled with a learning algorithm and some mechanism to evolve/improve its own code without altering its goals. One important benefit of such a probe is that it could quickly & efficiently explore the universe by creating multiple copies of itself.

**Q: Could you list all the necessary components to create such a probe?**

Where possible, please include references to published white papers and algorithms.

Comment: 1: ‘universal assembler’ isn’t a real thing. This is one of the major problems with the concept of a Von Neumann probe. 2: You won’t want the code to evolve. Either it’s fit for purpose or not. 3: Describing a full VonNeumann capable probe is Not Easy.

Comment: A 'Von Neumann probe' is a concatenation of two concepts - probe, i.e. a device built to survey things at a distance unmanned, and 'Von Neumann' a device capable of rebuilding itself perfectly, given access to materials and energy.

Comment: What's wrong with the [self-replicating machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_machine) article on Wikipedia?

Comment: That article is about self-replicating machines of which a Von Neumann machine is a type of self-replicating machine. The article does not even formally define what a self-replicating machine is or what it’s components are, let alone a Von Neumann machine. Also, I know universal assemblers aren’t real - hence I said ‘concept of universal assembler’.

Comment: What formal definition is needed? A self-replicating machine is a machine which produces another machine identical to it. The words have their usual meaning.

Comment: I’m not asking for the definition of a self-replicating machine. I’m asking the definition of a Von Neumann probe. That was part of my question.

Comment: The real question is what our current effective search radius for a Von Neumann probe is. The planet Jupiter has a habit of collecting interstellar junk for millions of years in orbit around it. How long until we can do a complete survey looking for ancient probes caught in it's gravity well?

Comment: Ideally, you make it out of what you can most easily find as you explore.  This is most likely going to be, Hydrogen, Oxygen, Nitrogen, and Carbon with only trace amounts of other elements as needed.  In short, the ideal Von Neumann probe closely resembles a biological lifeform.